# Fusion Tables Layer limited to first 100k results, but when I impose a 100k limit the points are different

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables

I'm putting data from Fusion Tables into a Google Maps Fusion Tables Layer. In [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer) it states:

> Only the first 100,000 rows of data in a table are mapped or included in query results.

So I would expect the data it returns to be the same whether I impose a limit of 100,000 or I don't and Google impose the limit themselves, but when I switch between the two in browser I can clearly see the markers jumping around because different positions have loaded.

If I load the same page up twice (either with limit or without) it loads the same data every time, so it's not a case of randomization of which results are returned, it just seems to differ between when I impose the same limit Google does.

Obviously I can't count 100k dots and find out which are which, but I want to use multiple layers to get around the 100k limit and I want to know if Google's limit is actually larger than they list it?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: I can't find a public dataset with 300k+ lat/lngs, and can't show the data I'm using so no can do at the minute. If there is a dataset available I'll put it together